# how can vlc act as a rtsp server?

Tags: vlc-media-player, rtsp, broadcast

hi I am trying to setup vlc as a rtsp server,I know there are two ways, broadcast and VOD.
can you tell me how to setup VOD server?

Comment: not a programming question , wrong website garima , try superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

It is quite an easy process:

Go to `Media->Streaming->Add(Add a local video file)->Stream(Click On It) -> Next(Click on it)-> Destinations->RTSP(Scroll down and select it)->Add(Click On it)->Uncheck Transcoding->Next(Click On it)->Stream(Click On it)`

Comment: and where can I find a stream link? ("rtsp://endPoint")